# HDMI to LCD RGB888 decoder IC

Tags: embedded, hardware

I'm working on the "**Allwinner H3**" core board in my project and I want to connect an LCD to it but it has only HDMI output and I have to use an **HDMI to LCD RGB888 decoder IC**, so I decide to use the **RTD2660H** but I don't know the quality grade of it. Can I use it in industrial projects? Has anyone had any experience using it?
Thanks.

Comment: What does the data sheet say about suitability for industrial use? And are you talking about just the RTD2660 as a chip or some board containing the RTD2660 chip?

Comment: I didn't find anything about the quality and use case in the datasheet, I want to use the IC and design my own PCB

Comment: What does "industrial" mean to you?

Comment: I should test the designed circuit according to IEC/TR EN 61000-2-3 EMC and EMI, I mean that dose it has enough quality to use.

Answer (score 4):

> Has anyone had any experience using it?

I have.

RTD2660H and RTD2662 are quite popular all-in-one display drivers. Couple of years ago I designed an RTD2662-based HDMI/VGA-input LCD monitor for trams and coaches (passenger info display). Although their temperature ratings are outside the automotive requirements *(Ta-max = 70°C versus 85°C)* the product, surprisingly, passed the tests and have been certificated. <sup>This is not an advertisement.</sup>

Few problems:

- **Availability:** That's the biggest one, especially if you aim for serial production. You can't find the chip from big suppliers such as Digikey and Mouser. You need to contact Realtek directly but, unless you are a big manufacturer (e.g. annual production of 300k units) they will simply ignore you. Contact others <sup>* *cough* * Far East * *cough* *</sup> at your own risk.
- **Technical Documentation:** This covers technical support. As I stated under availability, since Realtek will not give you even one second of their time, you won't get any technical support from them for both hardware and software design. I remember they were in a quite close relationship with Turkish large TV manufacturers such as Arcelik/Beko, Vestel and Sunny. Unless you are not like one of those, you have no luck. So all you have is internet: There are a couple of personal projects based on RTD2660/RTD2662 but I have no idea about their performances. Also there is very limited technical resource out there, but datasheets can be found everywhere (although they are quite limited in terms of technical content).

The only good thing is that you can find compiled firmware for different resolutions and LCD interfaces (i.e. LVDS or RGB). This saves you a lot of time of software development. But in order to use them the hardware should be exactly the same as the board that the firmware is designed for.

And if you are lucky, you can find a complete (?) software project but, even if you make a minor change the entire project will f*%@ up and you'll end up with a broken firmware.

Perhaps you can buy an RTD2660- or RTD2662-based board and reverse-engineer it, design your own board and flash it with one of the readily-available firmware.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiences